# Python3 regex pattern counting with optional period at the end

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x

I'm trying to count the occurrences of patterns using Python3 and regex.

My method is currently (based on another stackoverflow thread):

```
count = sum(1 for _ in re.finditer(r'\b{0}\b'.format(re.escape(vals)), doc))
```

However the search fails if 'vals' contains a period, such as:

```
vals = '42.'
doc = 'I like 42. a lot'
```

Of course to force this particular example to work I could include a period: `'{0}.'` but that work break values that don't contain a period at the end...

Comment: Why not just `len(re.findall(...))`?

Comment: `\.?` to match optional period.

Comment: @GarbageCollector ok, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wen vals is `42.`, your regex is `\b42\.\b`.  Here, the `\b` asserts there must be a word boundary, and because `.` is *not* a word character, that means it must not be followed by a word character.

You seem to always want your regex to be followed by a non-word character, whatever the last character of vals was, so just make your regex explicitly say that, changing to:

```
r'\b{0}(?!\w)'.format(re.escape(vals))
```

Similarly, you may want `\b` at the beginning changed to `(?<!\w)` (isn't preceded by a word character).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In fact I would like to account for non-word characters throughout vals if possible, not just periods at the end. Perhaps you could provide some guidance on this? How explicit do I have to be about non-word characters occurring throughout the string? Also, you removed the boundary from the right of the regex, will that affect the fact that I only want exact matches?

Comment: The `(?!\w)` is another way to specify a condition which is quite similar to a word boundary. The thing you look for must not be followed by additional word characters. I *guess* the rationale is that if `{0}` ends with a punctuation character, *requiring* specifically a word boundary at that point means that the *next* word *must begin* immediately after the match, which is not what you want, and presumably exactly what's tripping you up.

Comment: If `vals` is a static string, that's already as explicit as it gets. If not, we really need to see samples of the actual values. Perhaps post a new question with more details

Comment: Maybe start by saying in English what you hoped to do by putting \b at the beginning and end, since what it actually did wasn't what you wanted.  And explain what you mean by "exact match".

Comment: Thanks for the help @ysth, your answer solved my problem!